# How to check merge conflicts in a gitlab repository between two commits using GitLab RestAPI?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a FastAPI server with two endpoints, which are two commit ids.

How can I get the excact rows, where are conflicts between these two commits?

Comment: This is not python, fastapi or gitlab related. Check how to resolve merge conflicts in GIT.

Comment: In this task I'm not interested in resolving merge requests. I'm implementing a python server, which should write to the console the conflicted rows between two commits.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no official GitLab REST API endpoint for this.

You should also consider that not all conflicts necessarily deal with content of files. The merge strategy can also impact whether a conflict exists or not (for example, a squash & merge may work where a regular merge commit would not) among other considerations.

When the nature of the conflict allows it to be surfaced in the GitLab UI, the information can be seen at `https://gitlab.com/<namespace>/<project>/-/merge_requests/<MR_ID>/conflicts` however there is no API to retrieve this information -- it is strictly available in the UI.

*Gitaly* has a [list conflicts API](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitaly/-/blob/94f078df9c14593457a33cd70b845b7033bb2db9/internal/gitaly/service/conflicts/list_conflict_files.go) (which is used by GitLab, in part, to render the conflicts UI) but this is not exposed directly through GitLab's REST APIs.

So, in principle, this is possible to do, but probably requires use of `git`, as the implementation in *Gitaly* does, to list conflicts in merge requests.

It is possible to use the [Merge Requests API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html) to detect whether a conflict exists if an MR is actually open. However it requires an MR to be opened (which won't support arbitrary refs) and it won't describe the exact nature or content of the conflict.